# In php how to replace relative path to absolute path for images and download that php file as a doc file?

Tags: php

Mywebsite : www.test.com/abc/test

Php file: content.php

```
<!-- content starts here -->
<h2>Welcome test page</h2>
<p>This is test page.</p>
<p><img src="/abc/test/img.jpg" /></p>
<!-- content ends here -->
```

I have the function to execute the file and download as doc file.
I am using "include_once()" method to execute the PHP file also am using the appropriate header's to download that file as a doc file.

everything seems to be okay except images. Because am using 'relative path' to refer a image. Doc file is working fine with absolute path , but its not loading the images for relative path.

Question:
I don't want to replace content.php file with 'absolute path' for images. Using any PHP Pre-defined functions, there is a way to read file and replace 'relative TO absolute' path and download the file without modifying source file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use html `<base>` (inside `head` section) tag and set "root" for your images.

For example:

```
<head>
..
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/optional_base_folder_to_all_images/" />
..
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that getting the source code into a variable with file_get_contents and after, you can replace all your image path with an str_replace

For eaxample :

```
$source_code = file_get_contents(path/to/file.php);

$new_source = str_replace('<img src="/', '<img src="http://www.test.com/abc/test/', $source_code);
```